# JPA Repository : How to multiply column value by parameter value

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, jpa

I Want to multiply the value of moving from database by 'km' value from parameter and the return the result , When I am using the following query it gives me an error that parameter[1] with that point didnot exist

Please help how can I calculate calue ?

```
public interface FareRateRepository  extends JpaRepository<FareRate, Long>{

    @Query("select f.moving* :km from FareRate f where f.id=1" )
    float  calculateFare(@Param("km") Long km);

}
```

Comment: You can use parameters in the from clause not at arbitrary locations in your query. Also is this a JPQL or native sql query?

Comment: arbitrary locations means? @M.Deinum

Comment: Basically anything before the from clause.

Comment: since some JDBC drivers don't support parameters in the result clause (though some JPA providers support it, by other means)

Answer (score 2):

you missed the ":"

```
select f.moving* :km from FareRate f where f.id=1
```

Comment: just to confirm this is right?  f.id=1 or was it  f.id=?1 in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Query(value = "select ( f.moving * ?1 ) as fare from FareRate f where f.id=1", nativeQuery = true )
float  calculateFare(Long km);
```

**NOTE :** You have to specify the actual table name instead of `FareRate` in the query. And this will run a native query.